# ui.bootstrap dropdown directive in a flex container

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm going to use flexbox to layout the frame, however I found if I put `dropdown` directive into a flex container, it won't work anymore, here is the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/F2PQv7Ux3lTRTnRJZOdO?p=preview),

There are two options to make it work again,

1. Remove `width:100%; height: 100%` from `html, body`
2. or Remove `display: flex` from the only `div`.

I know that as children of a flexbox container, they are all treated as `flex-item`, I tried to override the display to `inline` and `block`, neither works.

So, is there a solution to make it run? if cannot, why?

Thank you.

Comment: I think that you need the [`flexbox`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox) tag instead of the [`flex`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) one.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the any flex attributes from the drop div that wraps the entire group of drop down components like this...

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown  layout="row" layout-align="center center">
//..drop down compoents
</div>
```

It seems fine to leave the layout attributes (if you are using layout attributes at all - angular-material), but removing any of the flex attributes will allow the drop menu to again line up correctly without adding any css at all.